# PHP Date to iCal date format for DTSTART

Tags: php, date, icalendar

Is there an easy way to get the correct format for an iCal DTSTART using php date?

I need the format to look like: 20111008T110000 or 20111008 (that one is easy) if I don't have any time.

Does PHP date have a quick way to do this, specifically one that adds the time or removes it when needed?

Comment: PHP date is a timestamp, it always contains the time incl. seconds. What are you looking for?

Comment: I think the answers below provide what I was looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There isn't any native PHP function or date format that I'm aware of, so you'll need to create your own function. Something like this:

```
function getIcalDate($time, $inclTime = true)
{
    return date('Ymd' . ($inclTime ? '\THis' : ''), $time);
}
```

As hakre pointed out in a comment, the date formatter can't distinguish between a date with time and a date without time - you'll have to decide the logic behind that.

Comment: aren't you missing a Z at the end?

Comment: @DanyKhalife: According to the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt), there are several accepted forms for the date-time value. The one without 'Z' is referred to as "date with local time", which means that there is no time zone information associated with it. Adding a trailing 'Z' puts the date-time into UTC ("date with UTC time"). Lastly, you can define the time zone explicitly ("date with local time and time zone reference").

Comment: oh cool, that's nice to know, i should spend more time reading those details :D

Answer (score 5):

```
date('Ymd\THis', time())
```

You can replace `time()` with your own timestamp.

Answer (score -3):

This is might be you are looking for [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) also can help you.

mktime function to make timestamp as you want including time or only date to it.

Comment: Down voted, question was asking for time format for DTSTART as per http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445

Comment: Also putting links isn't a good way to answer. Links can get outdated or broken with time.